# I want to create a circle which has a number in?

Tags: android, box2d, andengine

I want to create a circle like in picture below in Android andengine. It should have body by box2d. How can I create it?

[image: a busy cat]

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try this solution:

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(demoview);
    }

    private class DemoView extends View{
        public DemoView(Context context){
            super(context);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            super.onDraw(canvas);
            Paint p = new Paint();
            p.setColor(Color.RED);
            DashPathEffect dashPath = new DashPathEffect(new float[]{5,5}, (float)1.0);

            p.setPathEffect(dashPath);
            p.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
            canvas.drawCircle(100, 100, 50, p);
            Paint pp = new Paint();
            pp.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            canvas.drawText("kadir", 100, 100, pp);    
            invalidate();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try canvas.drawText(); function below drawcircle()

Comment: it works.the my last request: how i can i make it as body(box2d)?

Comment: "box2d pyhics engine" has a body elements.when you make two things as body, they can't stay the same place at the same time.namely they can collide not stay the same place.

Comment: ok another question:i wanna change color of text?   Paint p = new Paint();  
            p.setColor(Color.RED);  
            p.setTextSize(50);   
            canvas.drawCircle(100, 100, 50, p);  
            canvas.drawText("kadir", 100, 100, p);   
            invalidate();

Comment: p = new Paint(); p.setColor(Color.BLUE); canvas.drawText("kadir", 100, 100, p);

Answer (score 2):

Since the provided answers are completely irrelevant to the actually asked question, here the actual answer:

1. You can simply attach a Text entity to a Sprite that shows a circle.
2. Or have a look at the BitmapTextureAtlasSourceDecorators:
   https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngine/tree/GLES2/src/org/andengine/opengl/texture/atlas/bitmap/source/decorator .

   - This Example will be particularly helpful:
     https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngineExamples/blob/GLES2/src/org/andengine/examples/CanvasTextureCompositingExample.java

Regarding creating a body from an Entity, have a look here:
https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngineExamples/blob/GLES2/src/org/andengine/examples/PhysicsExample.java#L179